# Team task organizer

Tags: windows, gratis, offline, project-management, desktop-client

I am looking for a tool that helps me assign tasks that are connected with a certain workload to a number of people, and keep an overview of who is doing what and for how long.

Thus, for each task, the tool should keep track of

- how many hours will it approximately take
- when should work on it start
- who should work on it at which priority one which days

and for each team member

- how many hours do they have available

  - bonus points if this is computed automatically based upon a general workload per day + individual off-work days
- which tasks are they working on on which day

EDIT: As explained in the comments, please note that the focus of the tool should be the workload/capacity and planning aspect.

For instance, on usual bug trackers, there is e.g. just a field where I can set a fixed target date, as some kind of a bit of info. Rather than that, I am looking for a tool that supports me in determining and updating that date in the first place, based on the estimated workload a given task has, and the available capacity the team members that the task may be assigned to have.

I am looking for an overview from which I can quickly derive that team member A has two tasks this week which block approximately 90% of their capacity, while team member B has fifteen (tiny) tasks which block a total of some 20% of their capacity, hence I can assign a new task to B starting immediately, with support from A as of next week. And then, the output of the program I am looking for might be the expected date of completion.

Comment: Would you be open to a bug tracker? They are being called “issue management” these days. I see things like Jira being used for work burn-down. At the start of the project, define a bug (let’s call it an issue) that features X, Y and Q are  not yet implemented, give an “expected by” date for effort and assign it. Would that work for you?

Comment: @Mawg: Not quite; I realize a bug tracker could store the respective information (tasks, target date per task, assigned person) in a very basic manner. But, besides the fact that we already have a bug tracker (which is used for a much more fine-grained view on the tasks, though), I am looking for a tool that focuses much more on the workload/capacity and planning aspect. On usual bug trackers, there is e.g. just a field where *I* can set a fixed target date, as some kind of a bit of info. Rather than that, I am looking for a tool that supports me in *determining and updating* that date in ...

Comment: ... the first place, based on the estimated workload a given task has, and the available capacity the team members that the task may be assigned to have. I am looking for an overview from which I can quickly derive that team member A has two tasks this week which block approximately 90% of their capacity, while team member B has fifteen (tiny) tasks which block a total of some 20% of their capacity, hence I can assign a new task to B starting immediately, with support from A as of next week. And then, the *output* of the program I am looking for might be the expected date of completion.

Comment: That makes it clearer. Please add it to the question, as  not everyone reads all of the comments. I hope that you get an answer, as I would love that too :-)

Comment: @F-H - please how did you eventually solve this?

Comment: @ZZ: I'm sorry, I totally forgot I had once asked this question. In fact, I have recently asked a [partially overlapping question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/169200/is-there-a-standard-approach-for-keeping-an-overview-of-current-and-next-tasks-p) on [workplace.se], as I'm *still* not happy with the solutions I'm using now (essentially, an Excel sheet for short-term task assignments as well as for adding up total capacities.